# php simple Contact form re-submitting on Refresh of browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

The following form works as intended, including the honeypot, but if someone clicks on Refresh in the browser prior to finishing the form, it tries to resubmit. I have tried sessions but it is not working. Does anyone know how I can make the page redirect back to contact.php or end the session so it does not resubmit on refresh in the browser? ( I have spent 2 days searching for answers ). Thanks

Code:

```
<!--form-->
<?php
//fields
    $link_address   = 'contact.php'; // page to redirect to home page
    $honeypot   = '';
    $error      = '';
    $name       = 'Name (required)';
    $email      = 'Email (required)';
    $comments   = 'Message (required)';

    if(isset($_POST['contactus'])) {

    $honeypot   = $_POST['honeypot'];
    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $comments   = $_POST['comments'];

// honeypot
if($honeypot)
  exit(1);


//error messages
    if(trim($name) == 'Name (required)') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Please enter your Name</div>';
    } else if(trim($name) == '') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Please enter your Name</div>';

    } else if(trim($email) == 'Email (required)') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Please enter an email address</div>';
    } else if(trim($email) == '') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Please enter an email address</div>';

    } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid email address</div>';

    } else if(trim($comments) == 'Message (required)') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Please enter a Message</div>';
    } else if(trim($comments) == '') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Please enter a Message</div>';

    }
    if($error == '') {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $comments = stripslashes($comments);
    }

//email address
    $address = "email@youremail.com";
//email message     
    $e_subject = 'Web Message from: ' . $name . '.';
    $e_body = "From:    $name\nEmail:   $email \r\n\nMessage:\n$comments\n\n\n";

    $msg = $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply;
    if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))
    {
//success html page response
     echo "<div id='success_page'>";
     echo "<div id='thanks'>";
     echo "<h1>Message Sent Successfully.</h1>";
     echo "<p id='cprint1'>Thank you. Your message was sent to us. </br>We will be in touch shortly.</p>";
     echo "<p id='print'><a href='javascript:window.print()'>Print your Message</a></p>";
     echo "<p id='cclose'><a href='$link_address'>Close this Message</a></p>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "<div id='thanks2'>";
     echo "<div id='titlemsg'>Below is your message</div>";
     echo "<p><span>Name:</span> $name</p>";
     echo "<p><span>Email:</span> $email</p>";
     echo "<p><span>Message:</span>$comments</p>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "</div>";
     } else echo "Error. Mail not sent";
    }
}
    if(!isset($_POST['contactus']) || $error != '') // Do not edit.
    {

?>
<!--form-->



<form method="post" action="" id="myform" autocomplete="off">
<div id="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>

<input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form1" 
value="<?php echo $name; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name (required)') {this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Name (required)'; }" value="Name (required)" />

<input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="form1" 
value="<?php echo $email; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email (required)') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Email (required)'; }" value="Email (required)" />

<input name="honeypot" type="text" id="honeypot" class="form2"     value="<?php echo $honeypot; ?>" />

<textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" 
value="<?php echo $comments; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Message (required)') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Message (required)'; }" value="Message (required)"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>

<input name="contactus" type="submit" class="submit" id="contactus"     value="Contact us" />


</form>
<?php }
function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.
return(preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,12})$/",$email));
}
?>
```

Comment: you can use redirect after sumbit the form `header('Location: '.$newURL);`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your message in session on  successfull mail sent. and then refresh your page and check if session exist then show message and reset session.

Just redirect it to the same page after making the use of form data.
Example-

```
header('location:yourpage.php');
```

and you can also unset $_POST after inserting it to Database.

```
unset($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript redirect:

```
<script>
    window.location.href = 'test.php';
</script>
```